# Unable to update NSManagedObject using Magical record

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I am trying to update NSManagedObjects using magical record by fetching all objects and then using for loop changing every object and after saving context no change is there

```
 NSArray * locationArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[Locations findAllInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread]]];
for(Locations * currentLocation in locationArray)
{
    currentLocation.name = @"Hello world";

}
[[NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread]saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place you code in to the MagicalRecord's saving block

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    // This block runs in background thread
    NSArray * locationArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[Locations findAllInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread]]];
    for(Locations * currentLocation in locationArray){
        currentLocation.name = @"Hello world";
    }
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    // This block runs in main thread
}];
```